# UIButton not being instantiated

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I'm trying to instante a simple UIButton from a UIView already created in Interface Builder, but nothing's happening.
I've attached the following codes to the view:

"DetailViewTwo.h":

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewTwo : UIView

@property (nonatomic) bool viewIsShown;
@property (nonatomic) float lastY;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *radioArray;


-(void)createOption:(NSString *)legenda Value:(NSString *)value action:(SEL)action;
-(void)clearView:(NSString *)novoNome;
-(void)escolherRota:(id)sender;
@end
```

"DetailViewTwo.m":

```
#import "DetailViewTwo.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation DetailViewTwo

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _viewIsShown=false;
        [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        self.layer.cornerRadius=6;

        UIButton *but=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        but.frame= CGRectMake(100, 15, 15, 15);
        [but setTitle:@"Ok" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [but addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:but];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

(Oh, also, my 'self.layer.cornerRadius=6;' is not working either, is it related??)

Comment: Are you initializing DetailViewTwo somewhere as well? If not then the `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` won't get called. That's why you don't see the cornerRadius. To add the button just add it to that view in stead of its superview. `[self addSubview:but];` should add the button. If you still don't see the button then adjust the frame!

Comment: set self.layer.cornerRadius=6; in drawRect method of your view.

Answer (score 4):

If you have this view created in storyboard you should use
`-initWithCoder:` initialiser instead of `-initWithFrame:`.
Also you should add the button to self.view not superview.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        //Your code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to write exactly the same answer. You should also consider of using -awakeFromNib as a place from your UIButton initializaiton

Answer (score 0):

You need to add UIButton to `View`

```
[self.superview addSubview:but];
```

should be

```
[self addSubview:but];
```

Comment: [self.view addSubview :but];

Comment: @LightYagami `DetailViewTwo` is inheriting `UIView`, so use only `self`.

Comment: yes, but the instance of View inside the detailView is still a view isnt it?
and the name should come as 
[self.myviewname addSubview : but];
 I am not so sure so do correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @LightYagami we are using `self.view` when we are inheriting VC, and when we inherit UIView there is no need to use `self.view`, because `self` is `UIview`. Also try this in Xcode you will get your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

i have a solution to instantiate (add) button in view. As per your code, you just need to replace `[self.superview addSubview:but];` with this `[self.view addSubview:but];`.

```
 UIButton *but=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                but.frame= CGRectMake(100, 15, 15, 15);
                [but setTitle:@"Ok" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [but addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [self.view addSubview:but]; // Changes done
```

Comment: I posted the wrong code. The original one was already "self addSubview".